# "My kind of ___" in Spanish

Tags: selección-de-palabras

### Español

He estado buscando una manera de decir "My kind of **_**" en español. O una frase equivalente (que creo que es más adecuado y preferible). Como la manera que un estadounidense diría: "this is my kind of party!" cuando piensa que algo es guay/chido/bárbaro (muy bueno).

Pero principalmente para mi web. Tengo una página titulada "My kind of books!" que me ha llevado a esta pregunta.

---

### Inglés

I've been looking for a way to say "My kind of *_*_" in Spanish. Or a equivalent phrase (which I think is more likely and preferably). Like the way an American might say, "This is my kind of party!" when she/he thinks something is cool.

But mainly for my website. I have titled a page "My kind of books!" Which led me to ask this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can say things like:

- tipo de
- estilo de
- clase de

For example:

> **mi + tipo/estilo + de + something**  - or just -  **mi + tipo/estilo**
>
> María no es **mi tipo** (**de** chica).
>
> El rap no es **mi estilo** (**de** música).

In case you want to add a clause to indicate what is what you don't like to do with it you have to use a definite article instead of "mi" (in this case you can also use "clase")

> **la clase de ... que...** - or - **el tipo de ... que...** - or - **el estilo de ... que...**
>
> María no es **la clase de** chicas **que** me gustan.
>
> El Quijote no es **el tipo de** libros **que** yo leo.
>
> La actividad de ayer es **el estilo de** eventos a los **que** suelo ir.

Comment: Do 'tipo' and 'estilo' have different connotations?

Comment: @Luke Mostly the same difference as between "type" and "style" in English

Answer (score 1):

Kind is more generic word, you must refer to their equivalents on each circumstances

- Tipo -> Type
- Clase -> Class
- Estilo -> Style

Although the three of them looks similar and can be used on the exact same sentence, each one have its own particular meaning.

For example:

> BMW is the **type** of car that you will enjoy to drive
>
> BMW is the **class** of car that you will enjoy to drive
>
> BMW is the **style** of car that you will enjoy to drive

You could easily use kind on any of these examples. But...

- Cars and trucks are two type of vehicles. Type -> as in Category
- The sedan and the coupe have different class of interior. Class -> as
  in Quality
- A Ferrary have distinctive style if compared to other cars. Style ->
  as in Design

You will not use kind on any of these examples (I think).

For your website I will say **Type** since a more general description will suit all.

Type of books / Style of books / Class of books

All three can be used to describe the same qualities of the book

> Q: Que clase/estilo/tipo de libros te gusta leer ?
>
> A: me gustan los libros bibliográficos
>
> Q: Te gustan los libros de clase/estilo/tipo romantico ?
>
> A: No, no me gustan los libros de ese/a estilo/tipo/clase

Answer (score 0):

How about mi "preferido", "preferencia", "favorito", "calidad", etc?